# Python - How to concatenate Strings and Integers in Python?

Tags: python

I'm with some trouble getting this code to work:

```
count_bicycleadcategory = 0
for item_bicycleadcategory in some_list_with_integers:
    exec 'model_bicycleadcategory_%s.bicycleadcategorytype = BicycleAdCategoryType.objects.get(pk=' + str(item_bicycleadcategory) + ')' % count_bicycleadcategory
    count_bicycleadcategory = count_bicycleadcategory + 1
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Type Error, not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

My question is: Any clue on how I pass the "item_bicycleadcategory" to the exec expression?

Best Regards,

Comment: This is wrong, wrong, wrong. Why do you think you need dynamic variable names? You do not. You need a single dictionary.

Comment: Is this just a very unsafe and obscure way of writing (or meant to be): `values = {pk: BicycleAdCategoryType.objects.get(pk=pk) for pk in some_list_with_integers}` ?

Comment: Or thinking about it a bit more... `BicycleAdCategoryType.objects.get(pk__in=some_list_with_integers)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already using python's format syntax:

```
"string: %s\ndecimal: %d\nfloat: %f" % ("hello", 123, 23.45)
```

More info here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Answer (score 2):

First, `exec` is even more dangerous than `eval()`, so be **absolutely** sure that your input is coming from a trusted source. Even then, you shouldn't do it. It looks like you're using a web framework or something of the sort, so really don't do it!

The problem is this:

```
exec 'model_bicycleadcategory_%s.bicycleadcategorytype = BicycleAdCategoryType.objects.get(pk=' + str(item_bicycleadcategory) + ')' % count_bicycleadcategory
```

Take a closer look. You're trying to put the string formatting argument to a single parentesis with no format strings with `')' % count_bicycleadcategory`.

You could do this:

```
exec 'model_bicycleadcategory_%s.bicycleadcategorytype = BicycleAdCategoryType.objects.get(pk=' % count_bicycleadcategory + str(item_bicycleadcategory) + ')'
```

But what you really should be doing is not using `exec` ***at all***!

Create a list of your model instances and use that instead.

Comment: +1 for actually responding to the error message; also for the exec warning.

Answer (score 1):

for python 2.7 you could use format:

```
string = '{0} give me {1} beer'
string.format('Please', 3)
```

out:

> Please give me 3 beer

you could do many things with `format`, for example:

```
string = '{0} give me {1} {0} beer'
```

out:

> Please give me 3 Please beer.

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
exec 'model_bicycleadcategory_%s.bicycleadcategorytype = BicycleAdCategoryType.objects.get(pk=%s)' % (count_bicycleadcategory, str(item_bicycleadcategory))
```

(you mustn't mix `%s` and string `+` concatenation at the same time)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
exec 'model_bicycleadcategory_%d.bicycleadcategorytype = BicycleAdCategoryType.objects.get(pk=%d)' % (count_bicycleadcategory, item_bicycleadcategory)
```